# What are different among of Accept Yours, Accept Theirs and Merge in GitHub in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

The three command buttons  Accept Yours, Accept Theirs and Merge will display when I try to merge files  in GitHub in Android Studio?

1. What are different among of Accept Yours, Accept Theirs and Merge in GitHub in Android Studio?
2. In image 1, does Part 1 always display "Yours" content ? and does Part 2 always display "Theirs" content?

The image 2 is child dialog box of Merge.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: From the angle of Android Studio, it's `Yours`. As a Git term, it's `Ours`. `HEAD` in the 1st part indicates the changes are from the current commit in the working tree. The 2nd part is introduced from another commit by `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, etc. as  `Theirs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are different among of Accept Yours, Accept Theirs and Merge in
>   GitHub in Android Studio?

This is not specific to Android Studio, but it is common in git workflow. When git tries to perform a three-way merge, and it cannot resolve the conflict on its own at some case(Mostly due to two different versions of changes on the same line). You can read about this [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

> In image 1, does Part 1 always display "Yours" content ? and does
>   Part 2 always display "Theirs" content?

Yes, "Yours" means it is your local changes(Where your HEAD is currently at). "Theirs" refer to the change which other developers made at the same line(after your branch diverged from the to-be-pushed/to-be-pulled-from branch)

Comment: +1 for specifying this doesn't directly have a anything to do with Android Studio aside it being effectively a wrapper for the VCS